# date as name of field not recognized in ms access

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, vba, field

I have fields which have as name a the date of delivery, as you can see here:
[image: extract of the table]
I have around 75 columns like that. I have a bug when I want to compute the value P1 because it does not find the field. BTW, I have very stranges values for my coefficients T1, T2 (which are dates) and thus A and B which are datediff. There is the code:

```
 Sub vcm_fc()
    Dim db As Database, T As Date, longest As Integer, nearest_date As Date, rsb As DAO.Recordset, strsqlb As String
    Dim strsqla As String, rsa As Recordset, maturity As Date, T1 As Date, T2 As Date, P1 As Double, P2 As Double
    Dim a As Integer, B As Integer, j As Integer, rsc As DAO.Recordset, strqlc As String, settlementbis As String
    Dim settlement As String, maturitybis As Date, ym As Integer, ymbis As Integer
        Set db = CurrentDb()
        T = DateSerial(2020, 8, 15)
        nearest_date = DFirst("PricingDate", "fc_historical")
        longest = DateDiff("m", nearest_date, T)
         db.Execute "CREATE TABLE time_series " _
                    & "(PricingDate CHAR);"
        db.Execute " INSERT INTO time_series " _
            & "SELECT PricingDate " _
            & "FROM fc_historical " _
            & "ORDER BY PricingDate;"
               For i = 1 To longest
                db.Execute " ALTER TABLE time_series " _
                    & "ADD COLUMN F_" & i & " Number;"
                 strsqla = "SELECT PricingDate, F_" & i & " FROM time_series ORDER BY PricingDate"
                 Set rsa = db.OpenRecordset(strsqla, dbOpenDynaset)
                 rsa.MoveFirst
                 rsa.Delete 'delete the first row which is blank when the time series table is created'
                 rsa.MoveFirst
                 While (Not rsa.EOF())
                 rsa.Edit
                 maturity = DateAdd("m", i, rsa.Fields("PricingDate").Value)
                 ym = Year(maturity) - 2000
                 settlement = "1/" & Month(maturity) & "/" & ym
                 strsqlb = "SELECT Pricingdate, " & settlement & " FROM fc_historical ORDER BY PricingDate;"
                 Set rsb = db.OpenRecordset(strsqlb, dbOpenDynaset)
                 rsb.MoveLast
                 T1 = rsb.Fields("PricingDate").Value
                 maturitybis = DateAdd("m", i, maturity)
                 ymbis = Year(maturitybis) - 2000
                 settlementbis = "1/" & Month(maturitybis) & "/" & ymbis
                 strsqlc = "SELECT Pricingdate, " & settlementbis & " FROM fc_historical ORDER BY PricingDate;"
                 Set rsc = db.OpenRecordset(strsqlc, dbOpenDynaset)
                 rsc.MoveLast
                 T2 = rsc.Fields("PricingDate").Value
                 a = DateDiff("d", T1, rsa.Fields("PricingDate").Value)
                 B = DateDiff("d", rsa.Fields("PricingDate").Value, T2)
                 P1 = rsb.Fields(settlement).Value
                 P2 = rsc.Fields(settlementbis).Value
                 rsa.Fields("F_" & i) = (P1 * B + P2 * a) / (a + B)
                 rsa.Update
                 rsa.MoveNext
                 Wend
        Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I wouldn't design the table that way - looks completely opposed to relational database theory and normalisation.  Instead have 3 columns - PricingDate, OldFieldHeadingDate, Value.  Your table can then SELECT Value FROM Table WHERE PricingDate = #somedate# AND OldFieldHeadingDate = #somedate#.  You'll have multiple occurrences of the same date in PricingDate - maybe then use PricingDate and OldFieldHeadingDate as the Primary Key.  Rule 1 of databases - it's not a spreadsheet. :)

Comment: The fields are the settlement date and the trading stop two weeks before (around). Then the idea is to get a new time-sery table for all the differents period before the trading stops (in month). For each date, the new price is a weighted-average of the prices with the nearest stop-trading dates of the date + the period before the trading stops (wich we keep fixed). Moreover, I do not just have 3 columns but 75. However, if I get your idea, I can create an index for the date of settlements and then I can compute new prices, can not I?

Comment: Yes, the index would be a combination of the first and second field - no need for 75 fields, just three.  If the prices are computed you can easily write a query to work on earlier PricingDate/SettlementDate(?) records in the same table.

Comment: By the way, would you know how to put the name of the fields in a column and then to use them as primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have added as an answer so I can get the format for the code.  This code will take your date field names and place them as record values - you may need to muck around with the fld.Name to make sure it isn't US date format (8th Jan, 9th Jan, etc for your table example) along with the price for that date.

```
Sub Put_Field_Names_As_Record_Values()

    Dim DB As DAO.Database
    Dim OldTable As DAO.TableDef
    Dim fld As DAO.Field

    Set DB = CurrentDb()
    Set OldTable = DB.TableDefs("time_series")

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    For Each fld In OldTable.Fields
        If IsDate(fld.Name) Then
            Debug.Print fld.Name & " : " & SQLDate(fld.Name)
            DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO MyNewTable (PricingDate, SettlementDate, Price) " & _
                "SELECT PricingDate," & SQLDate(fld.Name) & ", [" & fld.Name & "] FROM time_series"
        End If
    Next fld
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub

Function SQLDate(varDate As Variant) As String
    'Purpose:    Return a delimited string in the date format used natively by JET SQL.
    'Argument:   A date/time value.
    'Note:       Returns just the date format if the argument has no time component,
    '                or a date/time format if it does.
    'Author:     Allen Browne. allen@allenbrowne.com, June 2006.
    If IsDate(varDate) Then
        If DateValue(varDate) = varDate Then
            SQLDate = Format$(varDate, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#")
        Else
            SQLDate = Format$(varDate, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy hh\:nn\:ss\#")
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

You can then run queries on the table:

```
SELECT  SUM(Price) 
FROM    MyNewTable 
WHERE   PricingDate<=#07/16/2014# AND SettlementDate=#01/08/2014#
```

Edit:  **Test on a copy of your database!!**
Edit 2:  Manually create the MyNewTable and set PricingDate and SettlementDate as key fields.

I've updated to convert the field name into the correct date - http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html
On my test it converted all dates to the first of each month correctly.

Comment: All the dates are in european format so it is first of August and first of September for the column. All the settlements are the first of each month.

Comment: For the format of the date, I solved my pb with the following code: `"SELECT PricingDate,#" & DateSerial(Year(fld.Name), Day(fld.Name), Month(fld.Name)) & "#, [" & fld.Name & "] FROM fc_historical WHERE [" & fld.Name & "] BETWEEN 0 AND 10000000000000 ORDER BY PricingDate"`

Answer (score -1):

Use properly formatted date expressions:

```
settlementbis = "#" & CStr(ymbis) & "/" & CStr(Month(maturitybis)) & "/1#"
```

And do listen to Darren about normalisation.

Comment: I tried before as explained [here](http://pauls-learningcurve.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/ms-access-functions-domain-functions.html) but the bug is still there.

Comment: Sorry, I missed you are creating columns with "dates" as captions. As already mentioned by others, you need to completely redesign your concept. Access is not a spreadsheet.